# Running the Watir Test Suite

Tags: watir

I am trying to run the Watir test suite that is included with the Watir source ([Github Source](https://github.com/bret/watir))

Using Ruby 1.9.2. Get the same results on Linux (executing firewatir tests only) and on Windows.

Executing the tests via `rake test` always yields:

> watir/commonwatir/unittests/setup/filter.rb:18:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method`run?' for Test::Unit:Module (NoMethodError)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended version of Ruby is 1.8.6 or 1.8.7. See [here](http://watir.com/installation/).

Version 1.9.2 is probably so new, that method run? is replaced with a cooler method.